# Why the error occurs: 'error: package com.mysql does not exist'?

Tags: java, mysql, maven, jdbc, jira-plugin

I am trying to link a MySQL database to my Jira plugin. I am using Intellij IDEA Community Edition, and it says the syntax is all good. I have the MySQL Connector .jar in my library (added through File->Project Structure), so it *shouldn't* be that, unless there is somewhere else I have to add the .jar file that it won't tell me. I had just the MySQL .jar added via downloading from [their website](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/c-j/) and it wouldn't work. I added the maven MySQL .jar and that didn't work. I added both of them and it still doesn't work. [My external libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bf3tg.png)

I am getting this error when I compile the plugin:

```
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
/C:/Users/USER/dynamicSelectCF/src/main/java/PACKAGE/DatabaseConnection.java:[11,1] package com.mysql does not exist
```

With this code:

```java
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.mysql.*;
   
public class DatabaseConnection {
    
    public static ArrayList<String> connection(ArrayList<String> population){
        population.clear();
        population.add("-------------------");

        Connection connection = null;
        Statement statement = null;
        ResultSet result = null;
        String url = Constants.getUrl();
        String username = Constants.getUsername();
        String password = Constants.getPassword();
        String query = "SELECT name, p_o_allowed FROM database WHERE p_o_allowed LIKE 'P%'";

        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
            population.add("mysql driver a no no");
            population.add(e.getMessage());
            population.add(e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        population.add("-------------------");
        try{
            population.add("trying connection");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
            population.add("trying statement");
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            population.add("trying result");
            result = statement.executeQuery(query);
            population.add("all 3 are a go!");

            while(result.next()){
                population.add(result.getString("name"));
            }
        }catch (SQLException e){
            population.add("Yeah we didn't get in fam");
            population.add(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            closeResultSet(result);
            closeStatement(statement);
            closeConnection(connection);
        }
        return population;
    }
```

I also have this in my pom.xml file which is directly from the [MySQL website.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-installing-maven.html)

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.20</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I know I do not need `import com.mysql`; however, that is the only way to generate the error on compilation into my terminal otherwise it goes to the try/catch and throws *"com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver not found by PACKAGE"*.

If you have any question about the population ArrayList, it is for dynamically populating a Select list for the Jira Plugin. And adding those errors and tests allowed me to see them in my Jira dev website.

Comment: The `Class.forName()` line hasn't been needed since 2006. Remove it. You can't get this error unless you do have an `import` statement somewhere for it. Remove that too.

Comment: @user207421 That is the issue. The `Class.forName()` is used to see if the project is seeing that mySQL driver in the library. The` import`, like I said in my post, is added to see the error in the console. Without those two all I know is jdbc:mysql isn't connecting and I had no clue why.

Answer (score 1):

You have specified an wrong dependency scope for a `mysql-connector-java`. The following dependency solves this problem:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.20</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

More information: [Apache Maven: Dependency Scope](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope)

Comment: This did not solve the issue. I do not believe it is an issue with the maven pom.xml. I believe it is an issue with the project library, even though I added the .jar file the way that every website I find says to add it for Intellij.

Comment: Have you checked this for your project? Intellij IDEA is not a health indicator as another developer might be using Eclipse, NetBeans, Visual Studio. Health indicator is a command line interface for Apache Maven because it is your build tool.

Comment: Please run the command `mvn clean test` for your project and attach the result.

Comment: @Dimitry Rakovets I couldn't run mvn clean test, it says that it is not part of a batch file. I ran this thing called `clean` in the Intellij Maven tab and it said `Failure to find com.atlassian.maven.plugins:jira-maven-plugin:pom:8.1.2 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced` I also ran atlas-mvn clean test and got this `[INFO] No tests to run.`

Comment: No errors after executing the command `atlas-mvn clean test` means your code is compiling. Try to collect in .jar with command `atlas-mvn clean package` OR `atlas-package`.

Comment: @Domitry Rakovets Yes, the code compiles just fine. It's the plugin that does not load properly. It says it is missing `osgi.wiring.package` after adding a mysql dependency to Maven. I posted a [question about that too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68673127/adding-mysql-mariadb-dependency-breaks-maven-jira-plugin) because it was different than this error. But, further testing is showing that that is the main problem right now.